# Java Oauth request_token flow example, without libraries

Tags: java, rest, authentication, oauth, restful-authentication

I have this piece of code:

```
String yourUrl = "https://api.discogs.com/oauth/request_token";
        String currentSeconds = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        String urlString = yourUrl + "?oauth_consumer_key=BaeIqWMTmCxjeJjwmkJr&oauth_nonce=random_string_or_timestamp&oauth_timestamp="+ currentSeconds + "&oauth_callback=http://localhost:8080&oauth_signature=ZWglyBtJasnJBqVnzyduYJggCduKeYks;

        System.out.println(urlString);

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");

        int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

but I have this error:

```
Status Code: 401
Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: ZWglyBtJasnJBqVnzyduYJggCduKeYks&
```

Comment: Looks like you missed & sign in the end of signature.

Comment: same result adding & in the end of signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discogs [oauth](https://www.discogs.com/developers#page:authentication,header:authentication-oauth-flow) flow you shouldn't send params as request params, but rather should send it combined into Authorization header and do something like this:

```
        String yourUrl = "https://api.discogs.com/oauth/request_token";
        String currentSeconds = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        URL url = new URL(yourUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
            "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"BaeIqWMTmCxjeJjwmkJr\"," +
                "oauth_nonce=\"" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\"," +
                "oauth_signature=\"ZWglyBtJasnJBqVnzyduYJggCduKeYks&\"," +
                "oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\"," +
                "oauth_timestamp=\"" + currentSeconds + "\"," +
                "oauth_callback=\"your_callback\""
        );

        int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```